# Selecting all rows with highest (relative) timestamp

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following simplified table structure in a SQL 2000 Databse:

```
ID  AppName  Key    Value   EffectiveDate
--  -------  -----  ------- -------------
1   App1     One    Past    1/1/1900
2   App1     One    Present 1/1/2010
3   App1     One    Future  1/1/9999
4   App1     Two    Past    1/1/1900
5   App1     Two    Present 1/1/2010
6   App1     Two    Future  1/1/9999
7   App2     One    Present 1/1/2010
8   App2     Two    Present 1/1/2010
```

I need to be able to ask the question:

Given a specific `AppName`, show me all **ONLY THE MOST RECENT** Key/Value pairs whose `EffectiveDate <= GetDate()`

So if I called my mystery query with `AppName = 'App1'` then my results would be:

```
ID  AppName  Key    Value   EffectiveDate
--  -------  -----  ------- -------------
2   App1     One    Present 1/1/2010
5   App1     Two    Present 1/1/2010
```

### EDIT:

Value can be anything. ('Past','Present','Future') were merely used to make the example more clear. They could very well have been (45,'Bob','%$#%@#$').

Comment: Thanks for telling us about that, but this is a Q&A site. Do you have a question?

Comment: the example results shown don't match the conditions stated - both 'Past' and 'Present' records have EffectiveDate <= GetDate(), but only 'Present' records are being returned. Which do you want to see - all rows, or only those with the highest timestamp in the group?

Comment: Ok, so I realized my question was worded poorly. I had *hoped* my example would be clear. @Mark - Has it on the head as I want only those records with the highest timestamp in the group. No Key should be duplicated in the result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use something like this:

```
SELECT T3.*
FROM your_table T4
JOIN
(
    SELECT T2.[Key], T2.EffectiveDate, MAX(T2.ID) AS ID
    FROM your_table T2
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT [Key], MAX(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate
        FROM your_table
        WHERE AppName = 'App1'
        AND EffectiveDate <= GetDate()
        GROUP BY [Key]
    ) T1
    ON T1.[Key] = T2.[Key] AND T1.EffectiveDate = T2.EffectiveDate
    WHERE T2.AppName = 'App1'
    GROUP BY T2.[Key], T2.EffectiveDate
) T3
ON T3.ID = T4.ID
```

Comment: Value could be anything... I was trying to be helpful with my example to make it clear :)

Comment: You would just remove the Value condition then. SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE AppName = 'App1' AND EffectiveDate <= GetDate()

Comment: Ok, I realize my question is worded poorly

Comment: @Josh: I think I understand your question now. You want a groupwise-maximum except that you only want to consider rows in each group that match a predicate.

Comment: Awesome! I realize now I should have payed more attention when I was in college and they were going over all that relational algebra.

Answer (score 2):

Something more like this to get the latest relative date.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE AppName = 'App1'
AND DATE = (SELECT MAX(EffectiveDate ) 
             FROM your_table
             WHERE APPName = 'App1'
              AND EffectiveDate <= GetDate())
```

Comment: +1 @Turnkey, I think the subquery should also link back to the main query on `Key` - different keys for the same app may have different effective dates (although they don't in the example.)

Comment: Won't this only return a single record?

Comment: That's right, it will only return rows with the max date for that AppName, to group it Mark's got the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a fairly basic SQL query:

```
select *
from App
where AppName = 'App1'
    and EffectiveDate <= GetDate()
```

There's a fair bit of information around on SQL queries, but this is a pretty good starter: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Sorry my question was worded poorly. I was hoping the example would make the specification clear. This will give me duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what the "Present" is.  Is it the last year?  The last decade?

Your query would look like this

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE EffectiveDate <= GetDate()
--This is where you need to define what "Present" is
AND EffectiveDate > DateAdd(YY, -1, GetDate()) 
AND AppName = 'App1'
```